# Best practice for asserting a positive IF condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

What's better - to leave the `IF` block blank to do nothing, or to add a statement that basically does nothing (each link already has a `href` attribute)?

```
export function fixRelativeLinksOutsideOfEpub(dom): void {
    const content = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('a');
    content.forEach((element: HTMLElement) => {
        const href = element.getAttribute('href');
        if (href.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    });
}
```

```
export function fixRelativeLinksOutsideOfEpub(dom): void {
    const content = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('a');
    content.forEach((element: HTMLElement) => {
        const href = element.getAttribute('href');
        if (href.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            element.setAttribute('href', `${href}`);
        } else {
            element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }out
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should NEVER! add superfluous or unused code.

Your code should have the single `if` statement checking for not equal.

```
    const href = element.getAttribute('href');
    if (href.indexOf('#') !== 0) {
        element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
```

or better yet avoid the overly complex referencing via get set attribute, and not using a search to find a known location state the whole thing becomes.

```
    if (element.href[0] === "#") { element.target = "_blank" }
```

And as a whole there is a huge amount of noise that can be removed

```
dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("a")
   .forEach(el => el.href[0] === "#" && (el.target = "_blank"));
```